# Traversals between two sets of nodes - keeping all edges in between

Tags: arangodb

I'm struggling to figure out how to collect edges with X steps between two sets of nodes.  I have a starting set of nodes (Set A) and an end set of nodes (Set B) - they could be the same set also, and I want to find all edges of <= X steps between those sets.  All of the traversal examples I saw were for node 1 to node 2 and not between sets of nodes.

A complicating factor is that I'm trying to collect edges using a LET edges_attr = (attribute-based selection of edges - all working fine) and UNION() it with a neighborhood-based set of edges (again works great).  I'd like to be able to add a third selection of edges between (Set A) and (Set B) nodes with step=2-5 (clueless).

I then take all of those edges and generate facet counts from them so I can get a set of edges and their facets from a search request against the graph database we have.

Nodes:

```
Set A: 0, 10
Set B: 8, 9
```

Paths:

```
0->1->2->9
8->3->4->10
4->5->6
```

I want to collect edges since they are on paths between the two sets of nodes:

```
0->1
1->2
2->9
8->3
3->4
4->10
```

Part of it seems straightforward:

```
FOR a in SetA
    FOR b in SetB
        FILTER a == b
        <what goes here?>
```

Comment: Looked into SHORTEST_PATH - but I'd like to set a length of allowed steps for the path.  This note was intriguing (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Graphs/ShortestPath.html#conditional-shortest-path), but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: What if there was another path `0->5->9`? Do you expect the edges of the paths `0->1->2->9` and `0->5->9` to be in the result, or only one of them? What is the traversal direction, always from an A node in OUTBOUND direction to a B node?

Comment: I do want to be able to limit the number of steps between node A and node B - e.g. Steps=3 - all paths with up to 3 steps between node A and node B - generally I'm looking for ANY direction.  I'd want both 0->1->2->9 and 0->5->9.